# .htaccess - subfolder URL Clearing

Tags: linux, mod-rewrite

I don't seem to be able to do the following in my `.htaccess`
I have my script in a sub-folder inside my root directory, let's call it "ecommerce", and inside that sub-folder I have my `.htaccess`. I Am trying to make going to a certain sub-folder inside "ecommerce" load a certain page within the 2nd sub-folder, let's called it "shirts".

Here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ecommerce/shirts/$ /ecommerce/shirts/shirts.php
```

Here are the address/locations of the the files and folders:

```
localhost/ecommerce/.htaccess
localhost/ecommerce/shirts/shirts.php
```

What am trying to do is, if I open

```
localhost/ecommerce/shirts/
```

I'll get access to my `shirts.php` inside, instead of the folder directory.
Ofc I made sure that I have mod-writing enabled on my Apache server.
Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a .htaccess in a sub folder, Apache [strips the directory prefix](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#what_is_matched) from the request URL. Therefore, the `RewriteRule` pattern must not include the directory prefix

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shirts/$ /ecommerce/shirts/shirts.php
```

Comment: I tried doing that, but I got the following: Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7

Comment: @Khaled Then you have no `example.php` in the `example-folder2` directory. I tested this locally and it works as intended. Please see updated answer.

Comment: I will re edit my original post, to include some data that might help and clear the confusion am causing here. ^^

Comment: It has been updated.

Comment: @Khaled Then the first rule works.

Comment: Restarted my XAMPP, and tried that rule again, and it worked. Thanks a bunch for your help. :)